# Displaying seconds in XNA with Keypress?

Tags: xna-4.0

I following [a guide](http://www.xnawiki.com/index.php?title=Displaying_seconds) to display seconds in `XNA`, but was now wondering how to make the seconds count-up ONLY when I press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. So, when I start the game, the seconds don't start automatically, but only when I press the spacebar.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you ask. All I did was add a `timerEnabled` variable and set to true in the updated method if the <kbd>SpaceBar</kbd> was pressed. I also added a line that won't start the timer until `timerEnabled` is set to true.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        //Put this variable at the top with the others.
        bool timerEnabled;

        protected override void Update( GameTime gameTime )
        {
            if ( Keyboard.GetState().KeyDown( Key.Space ) ) timerEnabled = true;

            if (timerEnabled) _timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

            base.Update( gameTime );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState()
if(state.KeyDown(Key.Space))
  _timer += ......
```

Something like that should help you on start.
Basically, check if key is down and if it is, add more time to _timer.